# Ignite server node goes OOM with huge accumulations in the ConcurrentMap, TcpCommunicationSpi#recoveryDescs

Tags: java, ignite, gridgain

When running in our scale test setup we notice that the ignite server node goes OOM after a few days of running.

On looking the heap dump i notice that the ConcurrentMap, **org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi#recoveryDescs** had accumulated a lot of messages ("Unacknowledged messages" per Java doc) in multiple entries of the map, namely the below ArrayDeque seem to hold a lot **org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioRecoveryDescriptor.msgReqs**

[image]

Any idea what may cause this kind of 'leak' to happen?

We do see issues with long transactions, locks, etc in the logs as well. But what worries me is irrespective of a few client nodes misbehaving which i suspect to be the case here that should still not result in the server node going OOM.

Any one have any clues, suggestions or inputs on this in terms of how to avoid/work around this? Basically even if one or more clients misbehave i would like to prevent the server node from crashing with OOM.

For example, would setting a lower value for slowClientQueueLimit help? Currently i have set it to 1023 which is one less than the value for messageQueueLimit which is set to 1024.

In this particular setup we simply have a single server node & about 25 odd client nodes and they are all running in a docker swarm overlay network (a few of these would update a lot of caches inside of a transaction, basically open trx, acquire locks on some keys, then update several of the caches via jcache apis before closing the trx, i suspect this locking of keys to be an issue but thats a separate one for which i will ask in a different question).

We are running version 2.4 & using Spring integration (planning to upgrade soon).

Thanks
Muthu

Update (10/16/18): Below is the TcpCommunicationSpi Settings on all nodes,

```
             <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi">
                 <!-- Override message queue limit for incoming and outgoing messages -->
                 <property name="messageQueueLimit" value="1024"/>
                 <property name="sharedMemoryPort" value = "-1" />
                 <property name="slowClientQueueLimit" value="1023"/>
                 <property name="idleConnectionTimeout" value="3600000"/>
             </bean>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try decreasing `org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi#setAckSendThreshold`. Default value is 32. Let's try 8 or less for ALL nodes in topology - servers and clients.

Explanation below.

In order to ensure communication messages delivery Ignite sends acks for each `org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi#setAckSendThreshold` messages recieved. In case Ignite node does not recieve acks for `org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi#setUnacknowledgedMessagesBufferSize` communication messages it closes the connection and resends all the unacked messages after reestablishing the connection.

From what I see (assuming all settings of TcpCommunicationSpi are left default) I would assume that your cache keys and values or job data if you use compute (i.e. Ignite messages used for transport) are pretty big, maybe tens or hundreds of megs. Therefore, decreasing `org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi#setAckSendThreshold` should help.

Let me know if it works.

Yakov

Comment: Thanks @Yakov for the helpful suggestion & reasoning. I will try it out & update.  We do have a few cache values that are slightly big. I also have a few non-default settings on TcpCommunicationSpi which i have updated above in the question. Hope they are fine. One question though, what is the current default value for this second setting?, `org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi#setUnacknowledgedMessagesBufferSize`

Comment: @lmk You can check logic here `org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi#recoveryDescriptor`. By default it should be `32 * 128 = 4096`, but given you changed `queueLimit` it is calculated based on provided value.

Thanks!